# Remove html tags in Oracle with < in text

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to remove all html tags. I use regexp_replace, but it fails when there is > or < character inside text.

```
WITH T AS
(SELECT '<HTML><HEAD>head1</HEAD><BODY>body<P>text: x > 200 and x < 1000;</P><H1>headline</H1></BODY></HTML>' STR FROM DUAL
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(STR, '<[^>]+>|\&(nbsp;)|(amp;)', ' ') from T;
```

output is: `head1  body text: x > 200 and x   headline`

should be: `head1  body text: x > 200 and x < 1000;  headline`

Answer (score 3):

If you have valid XML/XHTML (note: using `<` in text is not valid as you should be using HTML entities like `&lt;`) then you can use `XMLTABLE` to extract the text:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( str ) AS
SELECT '<HTML><HEAD>head1</HEAD><BODY>body<P>text: x &gt; 200 and x &lt; 1000;</P><H1>headline</H1></BODY></HTML>' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT X.*
FROM   test_data T
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/HTML'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( T.str )
         COLUMNS
           text CLOB PATH '.'
       ) X;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | TEXT                                         |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | head1bodytext: x > 200 and x < 1000;headline |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dee72a3c387bc197822f9dfe7daaa81d)*

---

If you want to use a regular expression (don't, use a proper parser) then a simple example is:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         STR,
         '</?[a-z0-9]+(\s+[a-z0-9](\s*=\s*(''([^'']|\\'')*''|"([^"]|\\")*"|[^"''=>< `]+))?)*\s*/?>|&nbsp;',
         ' ',
         1,
         0,
         'i'
       ) AS text
FROM   test_data;
```

*(Note: it does not handle the full range of HTML syntax as it won't match unicode attribute names and possibly other things; which would make the expression very complicated and is why you shouldn't use regular expressions.)*

which outputs:

> ```
> | TEXT                                                         |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------- |
> |   head1  body text: x &gt; 200 and x &lt; 1000;  headline    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16e40569299a658ad24ece3ae073fbb4)*